# How do I set the working directory for the Ant 'junit' task?

Tags: java, ant, junit

My Ant build includes a junit task that runs some tests. In order for the tests to work, the value of the property that specifies the current working directory (`user.dir`) must be changed, but I am unsure how to achieve this.

The task in question currently looks like this:

```
<junit printsummary="withOutAndErr" fork="true"
           haltonfailure="yes" showoutput="true"
           filtertrace="false" dir="C:/workspace/obp-web">
    <jvmarg value="-Duser.dir=C:/workspace/obp-web"/>

    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${web.lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </classpath>    
    <batchtest fork="no" todir="${web.build.dir}/testresults">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <zipfileset src="${web.build.dir}/test-obp-web.jar">
            <include name="**/*Test.class"/>
        </zipfileset>           
    </batchtest>
</junit>
```

Notice that I've tried to use both the "dir" attribute and the "jvmarg" task to change the working directory to C:/workspace/obp-web. However when I run Ant with verbose output turned on, I see the following output, which indicates that the working dir has not been set correctly:

> **[junit] dir attribute ignored if running in the same VM**
>
> **[junit] Using System properties**
>   {java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime
>   Environment,
>   sun.boot.library.path=c:\jdk6\jre\bin,
>   java.vm.version=10.0-b23, ant.lib
>   rary.dir=C:\java\apache-ant-1.7.0\lib,
>   java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.,
>   java.vendor.url=http://java.sun.com/,
>   path.separator=;, java.vm.name=Java
>   HotSpot(T M) Client VM,
>   file.encoding.pkg=sun.io,
>   user.country=CA,
>   sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD,
>   sun.os.patch.level=Service Pack 1,
>   java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification,
>   **user.dir=c:\workspace\obp-ear**, java.runtime.version=1.6.0_07-b06,
>   java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment,
>   java.endorse
>   d.dirs=c:\jdk6\jre\lib\endorsed,
>   os.arch=x86,
>   java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\donal\AppData\Local\Temp\,
>   line.separator=

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a jvmarg:

```
<junit fork="yes">
  <jvmarg value="-Duser.dir=somedir"/>
  ...
</junit>
```

Note that fork **must** be true on both the *junit* tag and the *batchtest* tag as the *batchtest* tag overrides the value from *junit*.  Jvmargs only work if junit forks a new JVM.

Comment: I tried that, but no luck. I've updated the original item with the info.

Comment: You cannot change the current working directory in Java by setting user.dir. Changing that system property is considered a user error.

Comment: @David That is true but we are instructing junit to fork a new JVM with that user.dir property, not modifying the property in a running JVM

Comment: Don't use this. It makes the native working directory inconsistent with the property. Thus strange effects like somefile.isFile() != somefile.getAbsoluteFile().isFile() will happen.

Answer (score 15):

Use the attribute "dir" (must also fork the vm):

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

Comment: I tried that, but no luck. I've updated the original item with the info.

Comment: Works much better than the "correct" answer by Kevin.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem as you.

I resolved it by making the batchtest fork to true :

batchtest fork="**no**" ..

to

batchtest fork="**yes**" ..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pathelement location? This worked for me.

```
  <classpath>
<!-- filesets, etc. -->
<pathelement location="C:/workspace/obp-web" />
  </classpath>
```